Joomla 4 Smart Search is not displaying results from articles created using MySQL
I just recreated an old Joomla 3 website using Joomla 4. After the new site was ready, I took all the articles that were in the old site and imported them in the new one using phpMyAdmin. Once the articles were in, I updated the workflow_associations table, and now all my articles show up in the back-end. I then ran the Smart Search Indexer and now all the articles appear in Smart Search Indexed Contents page.
The problem I have left is that when I search for a term in the front-end, articles that contain that term and were imported in the manner I described above are not returned. I found a workaround: If I edit the article and change its category, the Smart Search will then return it. But I have over 12,000 articles, so doing this article by article is not possible. I did use the category interface to change article categories using the batch function, but doing so does not make the articles appear in the search result (it seems the category change has to be done article by article).
Any idea why the batch category change is not working as expected?

Moving articles like that is a bit tricky. Is not just the content table and the workflow, but also the assets table. Check when you save a article if a new row is added to this table.

Thanks for replying. There's a quick way to repopulate the Assets table, but not the search tables, as far as I could tell. I finally gave up looking for an easy fix and wound up fixing the issue by running a macro that edits each article, adds a space at the end, and saves it.
